# safari downloads the file instead of opening the page

Tags: php, ios, .htaccess, safari, modx

Good afternoon, the [site](https://dentistry-minsk.by/) is on MODX, in all browsers except safari, everything is fine, when you open it in safari, a file with the name of the site is downloaded (I can't see the content, there is no Mac, I checked it in the emulator, in a real Mac the same problem) Hosting ActivCloud.by - from technical support, no support, not even moral support, I set up redirects in .httacces in accordance with their instructions.

Thanks for help

Comment: Please show .htaccess content, probably there is problem with incorrect handlers like the next:

    AddHandler ...
    AddType ...

Comment: can't dump all the code here, but I added the following code "AddType text / html .html .htm" it doesn't help